# How do you add images in psql for ruby?

Tags: ruby, image, video, psql

I don't know how to add images in my sql for my ruby web application.

This is the code i've tried in my views index.erb

```
<h1>Welcome to my blog page</h1>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<div>
  <h3>
    <a href="/<%= post.id %>"><%= post.title %></a>
    <p><%= post.body %></p>
    <img src="/images/download.png" alt="There's an image">
  </h3>
</div>

<% end %>
```

This displays the same image for every post which makes sense

This is the psql I used to make the posts in my index, how could I add the images in the table and in it's own row. Also would it be possible to add videos as well?

```
CREATE TABLE post (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(255),
  body TEXT
);

INSERT INTO post (title, body) VALUES ('post 1', 'Body Text 1');
INSERT INTO post (title, body) VALUES ('post 2', 'Body Text 2');
INSERT INTO post (title, body) VALUES ('post 3', 'Body Text 3');
INSERT INTO post (title, body) VALUES ('post 4', 'Body Text 4');
INSERT INTO post (title, body) VALUES ('post 5', 'Body Text 5');
```

Comment: if you really need to do it this way (you really, really, really shouldn't to), you could base64 encode/decode the blobs.

Comment: I've decided not to because it's been advised not to but i'm still not sure how i could i assign a different image for each in the index of  a web application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store your image in the database. Store in on the server in the file system. 
Also, check out this gem https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave